# Android: Drag an image: the image is below touch point

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I've been struggling for nearly a week now with the drag implementation. I've tried so many tutorials and sample codes from here but every implementation I tried so far had a flaw. This is the most simple one I found which ALMOST works is this one below. The problem here is with THIS one is that as soon as I touch the image it moved below the touch point. It can be dragged around but sort of hanging a few cm below the touch point. Thanks

```
package com.example.imagedrag;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class DragImage extends Activity {

       int windowwidth;
       int windowheight;

       private LayoutParams layoutParams;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);

              windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
              windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
              final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

              img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                     @Override
                     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                           LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img
                                         .getLayoutParams();
                           switch (event.getAction()) {
                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                  break;
                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                  int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                                  int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                                  layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                                  layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;

                                  img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                  break;
                           default:
                                  break;
                           }
                           return true;
                     }
              });
       }
}
```

My XML is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="126dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:src="@drawable/c1" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What about the solution?

Answer (score 1):

what about replacing

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
```

with

```
layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord-img.getWidth()/2;
layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord-img.getHeight()/2;
```

, I think this should fix your problem.
Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - img.getWidth();
  layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - img.getHeight()*2;
```

I guess this will work, it works for absolute layout. Don`t know exactaly why, but probably its counting the title bar or something else on the size/position.